how to get the concise interval of solution in ODE Picard theorem?
I encounter a version of Picard theorem (at the bottom),usually the ridius of solution is $\delta_0=\min \left\{ \frac{\rho}{M} ,r  \right\},$ on $\left\{\left|t-t_0\right| \leq r,\|x-\xi\| \leq \rho\right\}$,but the following is $$
\delta_0=\min \left\{\frac{1}{L} \log \left(1+\frac{L \rho}{M_0}\right), r\right\},$$
How could i get  $\delta_0=\min \left\{\frac{1}{L} \log \left(1+\frac{L \rho}{M_0}\right), r\right\}?,$ I try to explain it by using Gronwall inequality:
\begin{aligned}
& \|x(t)-\xi \| \leqslant \int_{t_0}^{t} \| f(t, x(t) \| d t \\
& \leqslant\int_{t_0}^{t}\| f(t, x)  -f(t, \xi) \|  +\|f(t, \xi)\|d t\\
& \leq \int_{t_0}^{t}L\|x(t)-\xi\|+M_0 d t \\
& =M_0\left(t-t_0\right)+L \int_{t_0}^{t}\|x(t)-\xi\| d t \\
& \leq M_0 \delta_0+L \int_{t_0}^t\|x(t)-\xi\| d t \\
& \Rightarrow \quad\|x(t)-\xi\| \leq M_0 \delta_0 e^{\int_{t_0}^t L d t} \\
& =M_0 \delta_0 e^{L\left(t-t_0\right)} \\
& \leq M_0 \delta_0 e^{L \delta_0} \leq \rho \\
&
\end{aligned}
$f(t, x)$ : Lipschitz continuous $\|f(t, x)-f(t, y)\| \leq L\|x-y\|$ on $\left\{\left|t-t_0\right| \leq r,\|x-\xi\| \leq \rho\right\}$ $\Rightarrow \exists 1 x(t)$ such that
$$
\frac{d x}{d t}=f(t, x), \quad x\left(t_0\right)=\xi,
$$
on $\left[t_0-\delta_0, t_0+\delta_0\right]$,
$$
\delta_0=\min \left\{\frac{1}{L} \log \left(1+\frac{L \rho}{M_0}\right), r\right\}, \quad M_0=\max _{\left|t-t_0\right| \leq r}\|f(t, \xi)\| .
$$
